# Is there any shortcut to reference the path of the first argument in a MV command?

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I often find myself using mv to rename a file. E.g.

```
mv app/models/keywords_builder.rb app/models/keywords_generator.rb
```

Doing so I need to write (ok, tab complete) the path for the second parameter. In this example it isn't too bad but sometimes the path is deeply nested and it seems like quite a bit of extra typing.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What shell do you use?  `bash`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use history expansion like this:

```
mv app/modules/keywords_builder.rb !#^:h/keywords_generator.rb
```

1. `!` introduces history expansion.
2. `#` refers to the command currently being typed
3. `^` means the first argument
4. `:h` is a modifier to get the "head", i.e. the directory without the file part

It's supported in `bash` and `zsh`.

Docs:

- [bash history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)
- [zsh history expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_13.html#SEC48)

Comment: I don't know whether to vote you up or burn you at the stake.

Comment: @Ben Jackson: most `csh` features inspire that kind of sentiment. :-)

Comment: Say if I wanted to get a proportion of the directory (e.g. everything but the last folder)? Is there a variation allowing me to do that?

Comment: You can use `:h` multiple times, e.g. `!#^:h:h`.

Comment: A great idea, but it's actually better to use `!#$:h` syntax to refer to the last argument, since the first one might be an option (e.g. `mv -iv ...`)

Answer (score 22):

And another way: [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion).

```
mv app/models/keywords_{builder,generator}.rb
```

In general,

```
before{FIRST,SECOND}after
```

expands to

```
beforeFIRSTafter beforeSECONDafter
```

So it's also useful for other renames, e.g.

```
mv somefile{,.bak}
```

expands to

```
mv somefile somefile.bak
```

It works in `bash` and `zsh`.

More examples:

- [Eric Bergen > Bash Brace Expansion](http://ebergen.net/wordpress/2005/10/07/bash-brace-expansion/)
- [Bash Brace Expansion | Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to type the first file name and a space, then press `Ctrl`+`w` to delete it.  Then press `Ctrl`+`y` twice to get two copies of the file name.  Then edit the second copy.

For example,

```
mv app/models/keywords_builder.rb <Ctrl+W><Ctrl+Y><Ctrl+Y><edit as needed>
```

Comment: I *really* like the idea.  I just can't find an easy way to "move backwards" to the space with the default bash bindings.  `Alt+B` four times?

Comment: `Ctrl`+`a`, `Alt`+`f`?  Or `Ctrl`+`r`, `Space`.  Or in `set -o vi`:  `Esc`, `T`, `Space`.

Comment: Oo!  `Ctrl+W` would be great here.

Comment: ... then `Alt+Backspace`, `Alt+Backspace`, `Alt+Backspace` to delete the file name part in the destination.

Comment: @geekosaur: Did you want to write that way up?  It's heavily based on yours, so feel free to do so.

Comment: that are the usual emacs commands, alt-backspace to delete word, ctrl-a begin end of line, ctrl-e end of line ....

Comment: Exactly.  (Well, aside from `Ctrl`+`w` which is standard tty behavior instead of Emacs' `kill-region`).

Comment: @flolo: The reason why `Ctrl+W` is better in this case is that it deletes until the previous whitespace, but `Alt+Backspace` deletes until the previous non-letter (e.g. `/` or `.`), so it requires more keypresses in this case.  I was trying to find the fewest keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

or `cd apps/models && mv keywords_builder.rb keywords_generator.rb && cd -`

Comment: instead of cd at begin and end I would recommend pushd /popd

Comment: a few extra keystrokes for exactly the same effect.

Comment: the difference is that the cd - works just one level - if you cd`ed into you directory with the intention the leave it with - your OLDDIR get lost

Answer (score 0):

Combined answers of Mikel and geekosaur with additonal use of ":p"

**use brace expansion to avoid first argument repetition:**

`mv -iv {,old_}readme.txt # 'readme.txt' -> 'old_readme.txt'`

`mv -iv file{,.backup}    # 'file' -> 'file.backup'`

**use history expansion to avoid first argument repetition:**

`mv -iv "system file" !#$.backup # 'system file' -> 'system file.backup'`

**the filename can be printed using the "p" designator for further edition:**

`mv -iv "file with a long name" !#$:p`

**then press "↑" to edit the command**