# Dynamic abbrev expand for the shell

Tags: linux, shell, emacs

Is there a function on one of the linux shells like the emacs dabbrev-expand?

Comment: See also: [shortcut to reference the path of the first argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505827/is-there-any-shortcut-to-reference-the-path-of-the-first-argument-in-a-mv-command) for different ways to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First to give a definition:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>describe-function<kbd>Enter</kbd>dabbrev-expand<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
...
Expands to the most recent, preceding word for which this is a prefix.
```

Given that `bash` seems to be most heavily influenced by Emacs, looking there first reveals a few possibilities:

[man bash(1), readline section](http://man.cx/bash%281%29#heading28)

```
dynamic-complete-history (M-TAB)
     Attempt completion on the text before point, comparing the text
     against lines from the history list for possible completion matches.
dabbrev-expand
      Attempt menu completion on the text before point, comparing the text
      against lines from the history list for possible completion matches.
```

By default (or my system at least), <kbd>M-/</kbd> is already bound to `complete-filename`:

```
$ bind -l | grep /
"\e/": complete-filename
```

You could re-bind it by putting

```
"\e/": dabbrev-expand
```

in your `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc`.

Note that it only seems to complete the first word (the command), and only from history, not from the current command line as far as I can tell.

In zsh, I can't see anything in the man page that does this, but it should be possible to make it happen by figuring out the appropriate [`compctl`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Using-compctl.html#Completion-Using-compctl) command ([Google mirror](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aAVmsj-zOfFwJ%3azsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_20.html+zsh+compctl&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au&client=ubuntu&source=www.google.com.au)).

Comment: thanks a lot! do you know how to call emacs-like bash functions which are unbound to a specific key?

Comment: You can bind them to a specific key to call them.