# How can I use a shell command parameter as an argument?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to reuse the parameter I give to a shell command as an argument, e.g.

```
>sed 's/old/new/g'  inputfile  >  $?.outputsuffix
```

so that the result of `sed` is streamed to a file called "inputfile.outputsuffix".

I want a feature which works interactively at the Bash command line, not inside a script.  Is such a thing available?

Comment: Then it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505827/is-there-any-shortcut-to-reference-the-path-of-the-first-argument-in-a-mv-comman -- unfortunately, I can't close as duplicate again, but I invite you to do it yourself.

Comment: name=inputfile sed 's/old/new/g'  $name  >  $name.outputsuffix